# Difference with merging?

Tags: git

I have a project with two branches, one is master, and another is develop.

I am always on the master branch and when developers push their changes to develop branch I do git pull origin develop, and then git push origin master. That way I keep those branches up to date.

Another colleague of mine suggested I should do git merge origin develop, but I don't know what would be the difference between my way and his way since we both get the same result in the end.

Anyone with experience can weigh in and explain it to me?

Thank you!

Comment: You should definitely *not* run `git merge origin develop` unless you know a great deal about Git. If he meant `git merge origin/develop`, that's another thing entirely.

Comment: What purpose does `master` server in your case? If you simply want to keep them in sync, then you probably don't even need both branches. But if there is a difference, then this would affect how and when you should do merges.

Comment: A `develop` branch is typically associated with Git Flow. Are you using Git Flow, and if yes, are you using `release` branches?

Comment: @torek I can't think of a useful workflow where you would want to run `git merge origin develop` even if you *do* know a great deal about Git! ;)

Comment: @TTT: it would be odd, at the least. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are acting as a kind of *gatekeeper*. There are two long-lived branches, `master` and `develop`. Development takes place on `develop`; nothing happens on `master` except that every so often you merge `develop` into `master`.

Since your server doesn't do pull requests, then what you are doing is fine:

```
git switch master
git pull origin develop
git push origin master
```

You friend who says to do `git merge origin develop` probably doesn't say that. It makes no sense.

Your friend probably actually says or means `git merge origin/develop`. That's a good thing to say, but it omits a step: `get fetch`.

So you could instead proceed like this:

```
git fetch
git switch master
git merge origin/develop
git push origin master
```

From one point of view, that would not gain you anything you don't already have, because `pull` is the same as `fetch` followed by `merge` of the named branch. However, I agree with your colleague: I like it better, because after the `fetch` you can *look* at `origin/develop` and think what's about to happen.

In my opinion, it is best to have a merge commit when you merge from `develop` to `master`, to clarify the history. To ensure that, I would recommend saying `--no-ff` as you `pull` or `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `git pull` is actually a composite operation.  Doing `git pull origin develop` means one of the following two things:

```
git fetch origin + git merge origin/develop   (merge strategy)
- or -
git fetch origin + git rebase origin/develop  (rebase strategy)
```

If your pull strategy already be set to `merge`, which is usually the default setting, then you are already doing a merge with `origin/develop` under the hood when you do your `git pull origin develop`.